# Visual studio update required, SDK is installed

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to build a Windows app with Visual Studio freshly installed.

When I start a new project, I get this message.

> Visual Studio update required
>
> One or more projects require a platform SDK (UAP, Version:
>   10.0.0.0) that is either not installed or is included as pat of a future update to Visual Studio.  Install the platform SDK to open
>   these projects.

When I click install, I arrive on the homepage of Microsoft without any download link, which is kinda useless!

But as you can see on the screenshot below, I have latest version installed:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to change visual studio in program and settings. I then modified it -> removing all the windows universal app options.

[image]

then

**[image: Then]**

I then modified it again and added the windows universal app options back. *This was after trying to download and install the universal windows SDK as a stand alone. Which did not work*

Comment: Fresh install was what worked for me. I guess that there are no other solutions (or will accept one if someone post it)

Answer (score 5):

For me it was simply a matter of editing the project file (right-click the project and choose **Edit [project name]**) and changing the following line:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10586.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

to

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.14393.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

Clicking **Reload Project** command after this change made VS open it for me.

Worth noting that I updated my VS2015 with Update 3 which probably installed the newest version of the SDK for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check target version in your working latest working project:

Right click on your project in Visual Studio -> Properties -> Application -> Targeting -> Target Version (Build 14295 in my case)

2. Change target version in failed project:

Right click on your failed project in Visual Studio -> Edit -> Change target version -> Right click on project again -> Reload

That's all folks!